# get month & year from Mysql Date format m/d/y & compare with today's month & year

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have mysql date format m/d/y as varchar like 03/12/2015 for 12 March 2015. Now I want to count all the result from mysql table in which the month & year are the same as of today's date.

I am using following query, but no sucess

```
SELECT * FROM student where DATE_FORMAT(regd_date,'%m/%y')=DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%m/%y')"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: MySQL's `COUNT()` aggregate function is an option.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried but no success. it's showing nothing

Comment: You've been given an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your `varchar` column to a `date` before using `DATE_FORMAT()`.

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regd_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%m/%y') = DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%m/%y')
```

Adjust the format for `STR_TO_DATE()` accordingly.

**Note:** I would discourage storing dates as varchars.

Comment: I am checking your answer & will marked as answer, if it will work